# Pass DataTable To Another Class - ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to pass a datatable to the DataAccessLayer from aspx.cs page. DAL is another project and CountryDal is a class file in it.
Unable to do it using the session object. What is the proper way to acheive this.

**ASPX.CS**

```
private countryDAL objDAL = new CountryDAL();

protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //code...
  Session["tbl"] = dt;    //dt is a datatable with some data
  objDAL.SaveTable();
}
```

**DAL**

```
public void SaveTable()
{
  DataTable dtSave = (DataTable)Session["tbl"];

  //code.....
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inject it into the method:

```
public void SaveTable(DataTable dtSave)
```

so then, when you call it, just do this:

```
objDAL.SaveTable(dt);
```

and you can get rid of this line:

```
Session["tbl"] = dt;
```

Comment: Tried That. It says 'Value cannot be null. Parameter:Table'

Comment: @Ruby, then that means the `dt` reference you have in the ASPX page is `null`. You'll have to fix that up; but injecting it into another layer is *not the issue.*

Comment: Thank you very much. My mistake was sending a null dt.

Comment: @Ruby, no worries. I'm glad I could be of assistance!